# SignalR + Nginx + 2 Angular Apps throws 405 error on `SOME` hubs

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nginx, signalr

### Small prehistory:

I have 1 server, 1 Asp.Net Core app, nginx, 2 angular apps being hosting on the same Linux Debian server.
My use of SignalR is as: 2 apps getting data from same SignalR hubs. I have 2 hubs. 1 is working perfectly for 2 apps, 1 is working perfectly for one app and doesn't work for another one(but they are using from practically the same code). May I ask for some ideas why this error pops up? Thank You for any help.

P.S. everything works perfectly well on local machine.

### Configurations:

#### Asp.Net Core:

```cs
 app.UseRouting();

            // ToDo: update. This for develop only
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<EventStageHub>("hubs/event-stage");
                endpoints.MapHub<StageActionHub>("hubs/event-stage-action");
            });
```

#### Nginx:

```
location /client { 
    alias /home/ignatella/evr/client/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /client/index.html;
  }       
      
  location / { 
    alias /home/ignatella/evr/fia/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }         
           
  location /api/hubs/ {
     proxy_pass https://localhost:5001/hubs/;

     # Configuration for WebSockets
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_cache off;

     # Configuration for ServerSentEvents
     proxy_buffering off;

     # Configuration for LongPolling or if your KeepAliveInterval is longer than 60 seconds
     proxy_read_timeout 100s;

     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }         
  
  location /api/ { 
    proxy_pass           https://localhost:5001/;        
    proxy_http_version   1.1;
    proxy_set_header     Host $host;
    proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

#### Angular client:

```js
createHubConnection(eventId: string, modeType: string, actionTypes: string): void {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(environment.hubEventStageAction +
        `?eventId=${eventId}&stageType=${modeType}&actionTypes=${actionTypes}`, {
      })
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.start().catch(error => console.log(error));

    this.hubConnection.on('OnActionReceived', (nodes: Node[]) => {
      ...
    });
```

### Logs:

#### Asp.NET Core:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.0 POST https://.../hubs/event-stage-action/negotiate?eventId=cb8c1cff-ff06-48d8-9771-c6479e5ffb10&stageType=chat&actionTypes=send-message&negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'hubs/event-stage-action/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'hubs/event-stage-action/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.0 POST https://.../hubs/event-stage-action/negotiate?eventId=cb8c1cff-ff06-48d8-9771-c6479e5ffb10&stageType=chat&actionTypes=send-message&negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0 - 200 316 application/json 2.3196ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.0 GET https://.../hubs/event-stage-action?eventId=cb8c1cff-ff06-48d8-9771-c6479e5ffb10&stageType=chat&actionTypes=send-message&id=ezucHrXZ75iahsYaER3Chw - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'hubs/event-stage-action'
```

#### Nginx:

```
no errors in error.log. Only `status 200` responses in access.log
```

## Error:

```
POST https://---/hubs/event-stage-action/negotiate?eventId=cb8c1cff-ff06-48d8-9771-c6479e5ffb10&stageType=chat&actionTypes=send-message&negotiateVersion=1 405
Utils.js:228 [2021-05-06T22:12:07.047Z] Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error'.
chat-messages.service.ts:32 Error
    at new HttpError (Errors.js:25)
    at FetchHttpClient.<anonymous> (FetchHttpClient.js:152)
    at step (FetchHttpClient.js:51)
    at Object.next (FetchHttpClient.js:32)
    at fulfilled (FetchHttpClient.js:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:368)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28528)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:367)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:130)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1272
```

### Solution:

The error appeared simply because of incorrect URI in one of the 2 apps.
`Conclusion`: Be careful when setting up the routs ))))

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the location order in the nginx config file.
The signalr hub connection seems to try to connect to `location /` instead of `location /api/hubs`, as all requests will be caught by `index.html`. Try moving the `location /` part below the `api` part.

Comment: Oh my God, thanks for Yours answer i have pointed that i have `SIMPLY INCORRECT URI` without 'api' part in angular app. 2 days of debugging...... THANK YOU A LOT!!!! Mark the answer as a solution.

Comment: these types of bugs are the worst. I'm glad to help you out - somehow :)